# If I have a 0 in column B, I want to set the row next to it in column A to be blank, how?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I feel like the title summarizes it pretty well, but will try to explain further. As of right now I am using conditional formatting to hide the 0's in column B, but I have data in column A that I also want to hide if the 0 condition is true. For example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Michael | 90 |
| Dave | 0 |
| Mark | 24 |

I have a macro to sort the data from largest to smallest for columns A & B, but then I would like to "hide" Dave from column A considering he has a 0 in the row next to his name. Like I said earlier, I have conditional formatting to hide all of the 0's in column B, but am struggling to find the correct way to hide the information in column A. Please let me know if you can help!

Comment: Use the same type of rule.  apply the rule to column A.  With the formula: `=$B1=0`.

Comment: So close but you got me there! : =$B1<=0, Thank you so much for your help Scott!